# What is the difference between RU and CU in Homeworld: Deserts of Kharak?

Tags: homeworld-deserts-of-kharak

**What is RU (what does it stand for) and CU (what does it stand for) in Homeworld: Deserts of Kharak?**

I have search the internet but can't find any answer to this. "RU" and "CU" are referenced numerous times but there's nothing explaining which colour is which (one is bluish one is orangeish I think).

- What is an RU (that is collected by the salvagers)?
- What is a CU (that is collected by the salvagers)?
- And what is the main differences between these two things (I've read that in some campaign situations one should be collected more than another but it's not clear why).

*The only thing that "RU" and "CU" both seem to apply to is the Earth 5G network hardware IRL!*

Comment: PS> I have not yet played Homeworld - I wanted to play them in order.